# Why Karma Coverage is showing "statement not covered" when it actually is?

Tags: unit-testing, ionic3, code-coverage, angular-test, karma-coverage

My Karma Coverage report is showing a lot of "statement not covered" when these actually are.

I know that the "not called statements" are indeed called as:
- I expressly wrote tests for these
- even the report shows "1x" next to the "not called" statements.

The latter means that it's called once, right?

[image: Seemingly wrong coverage report]

So I was wondering if there was a configuration stipulating that a statement is not considered as "called" unless it is called a given number of times? If yes, I also didn't find anything related to such a configuration.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
I created a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/Gregordy/e0f4486424c90cf8320e456dc6d525cc) with the 5 files that may help in troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the "culprit".

This case happens for the methods I mocked. The real implementation not being called, it is detected as not being covered, which totally makes sense.

Comment: if you use `spyOn(component, 'method').and.callThrough()` you should get coverage for those statements